# [PostgreSQL]: Subquery has too many columns

Tags: postgresql, greenplum

I am trying to run a query, but the result is showing the error message "Subquery has too many columns". I have to change where the clause with array to string but the error is the same. could you help me, if you have any suggestions or different queries as modify to solve this?

the query is:

```
create table my_schema.table_1 as select a.*
            , O.ID1
            , J.ID2
            , K.ID3
            , L.ID4
            , M.ID5
            , S.ID6
            , O.plan_name plan_name1
            , J.plan_name plan_name2
            , K.plan_name plan_name3
            , L.plan_name plan_name4
            , M.plan_name plan_name5
            , S.plan_name plan_name6
            from (
            select
                  PRD_ID
                , NBR
                , SI
                , START_TIME
                , ATTR4
                , G_ID
                , BYTE_UP
                , BYTE_DOWN
                , LIST
                , TYPE_ID1
                , TYPE_ID2
                , TYPE_ID3
                , TYPE_ID4
                , TYPE_ID5
                , TYPE_ID6
                , CHARGE1, CHARGE2, CHARGE3, CHARGE4, CHARGE5, CHARGE6
            from my_schema.source where prd_id = '20200101'
            and TYPE IN (3) ) a
            left outer join (select distinct id, price_plan_name from my_schema.id_ref_v9) O on split_part(split_part(list,';',1),',',1) = O.id 
            left outer join (select distinct id, price_plan_name from my_schema.id_ref_v9) J on split_part(split_part(list,';',2),',',1) = J.id 
            left outer join (select distinct id, price_plan_name from my_schema.id_ref_v9) K on split_part(split_part(list,';',3),',',1) = K.id 
            left outer join (select distinct id, price_plan_name from my_schema.id_ref_v9) L on split_part(split_part(list,';',4),',',1) = L.id 
            left outer join (select distinct id, price_plan_name from my_schema.id_ref_v9) M on split_part(split_part(list,';',5),',',1) = M.id 
            left outer join (select distinct id, price_plan_name from my_schema.id_ref_v9) S on split_part(split_part(list,';',6),',',1) = S.id
            WHERE (
            O.id in (select * from my_schema.LIST_PRICEID4)or
            J.id in (select * from my_schema.LIST_PRICEID4)or
            K.id in (select * from my_schema.LIST_PRICEID4)or
            L.id in (select * from my_schema.LIST_PRICEID4)or
            M.id in (select * from my_schema.LIST_PRICEID4)or
            S.id in (select * my_schema.LIST_PRICEID4))
```

Comment: Those `select * ...` should be replaced with `select some_column ...` for the `IN` conditions.

Comment: I have to try to `select some column` for the `IN` condition, the column is the same, that's only two-column, there are `id, price_plan_name`. but the error is the same.

Comment: then it needs to be `select id from ...`

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot. I already try your suggestions, its work. so the conclusion is I can't put all columns for the  `IN` conditions right?

Comment: The number of columns for the sub-query (on the right hand side of the `IN`)  must match the number of columns on the left hand side, e.g `id in (select id from ...)` or `(c1, c2) in (select col1, col2 from ...)`